# Java 8 Stream sort map of string to list<String> based on list<String>

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a map with key as string and value as list of strings

I want to sort the map based on the list of strings(Lexicographically).

If I have a `List<List<String>>` then I can sort by

```
List<List<String>> sortedlist = new LinkedList<>();
sortedlist.sort((l1, l2) -> l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0)));
```

But I have a `Map<String, List<String>>` sortedMap and I want to sort this based on the values, i.e. first element of each list within the value set of the map.

I am trying to form a stream lambda expression something like this.

```
HashMap<String, List<String> > sortedmap = new HashMap<>();
sortedmap = map.values().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((l1, l2) -> l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0))) )
```

But it is not a valid lambda expression.

How do I do this with Java 8 streams?

Comment: HashMap<String,List<String>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> sortedMap = 
    map.entrySet() 
       .stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(l -> l.get(0))))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Note that sorting would not make any sense while collecting into a `HashMap`, since it's unordered.

Comment: This works. Thanks. Now trying to collect and print straightaway using foreach

Comment: @DeepakSelvakumar Glad it helped.